# Ho to parse and get element of an xml using Python data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my XML string i am getting this as a message so it is not a file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OperationStatus xmlns:ns2="summaries">
   <EventId>123456</EventId>
   <notificationId>123456</notificationId>
   <userDetails>
      <clientId>client_1</clientId>
      <userId>user_1</userId>
      <groupIds>
         <groupId>123456</groupId>
         <groupId>123457</groupId>
      </groupIds>
   </userDetails>
</OperationStatus>
```

I want to get output in below format

```
message,code,Id
```

I have mentioned only three elements but i can have many more elements .

This is how i am trying but not getting the exact output

I started learning Python so excuse me for silly mistakes

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    import pandas as pd
    
    def lambda_handler():
    
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
    
    xtree = et.parse('''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OperationStatus xmlns:ns2="summaries">
   <EventId>123456</EventId>
   <notificationId>123456</notificationId>
   <userDetails>
      <clientId>client_1</clientId>
      <userId>user_1</userId>
      <groupIds>
         <groupId>123456</groupId>
         <groupId>123457</groupId>
      </groupIds>
   </userDetails>
</OperationStatus>''')
    xroot = xtree.getroot()
    
    df_cols = ["message", "code", "Id"]
    rows = []
    
    for node in xroot:
        s_name = node.attrib.get("message")
        s_mail = node.find("code").text if node is not None else None
        s_grade = node.find("Id").text if node is not None else None


lambda_handler()
```

Comment: How is your Dataframe created? What is the purpose of `lambda_handler`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try using XPath, it will be easier to retrieve the wanted data

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

xtree = et.fromstring("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name xmlns:ns2="summaries">
   <message>5jb10x5rf7sp1fov5msgoof7r</message>
   <code>COMPLETED</code>
   <Id>dfkjlhgd98568y</Id>
</name>""")

keys = ["message", "code", "Id"]

data = {k: [xtree.find(".//"+k).text] for k in keys}

print(pd.DataFrame(data))
# Outputs:
#                      message       code              Id
# 0  5jb10x5rf7sp1fov5msgoof7r  COMPLETED  dfkjlhgd98568y
```

Comment: This does not work if we have two levels of xml element . i did find this easy solution but does `.//` has to play role if we have multi layer xml ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the output you desire?

```
# !pip install xmltodict
import xmltodict
xml = """
<name xmlns:ns2="summaries">
   <message>5jb10x5rf7sp1fov5msgoof7r</message>
   <code>COMPLETED</code>
   <Id>dfkjlhgd98568y</Id>
</name>
"""

d = xmltodict.parse(xml)
print(d['name']['message'])
print(d['name']['code'])
print(d['name']['Id'])
```

Output

```
5jb10x5rf7sp1fov5msgoof7r
COMPLETED
dfkjlhgd98568y
```

More info on `xmltodict` at https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict

Answer (score 1):

Given your string:

```
your_string='''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name xmlns:ns2="summaries">
   <message>5jb10x5rf7sp1fov5msgoof7r</message>
   <code>COMPLETED</code>
   <Id>dfkjlhgd98568y</Id>
</name>'''
```

Since this is a string, you would use [.fromstring()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring) rather than [.parse()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse). That automatically finds the root node `name` for you (ie, no need to call `.getroot()`):

```
root = et.fromstring(your_string)

>>> root
<Element 'name' at 0x1050f51d0>
```

Once you have the data structure with `name` as the root, you can either iterate over the sub elements:

```
df_cols = ["message", "code", "Id"]

for node in root:
    if node.tag in df_cols:
        print({node.tag:node.text})
```

Prints:

```
{'message': '5jb10x5rf7sp1fov5msgoof7r'}
{'code': 'COMPLETED'}
{'Id': 'dfkjlhgd98568y'}
```

Or you can use an xpath [query](http://xpather.com/jWCJdMoO) to find each element of interest:

```
for k in df_cols:       
    print({k:root.find(f'./{k}').text})  
# same output
```

Now since a data frame can be constructed by `{key:[list_of_elements],...}` you can construct that type of dict from what we have built here:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({k:[root.find(f'./{k}').text] for k in df_cols})
```

If you have multiple elements, use `findall`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({k:[x.text for x in root.findall(f'./{k}')] for k in df_cols})
```